# JDBC - Retrieving Resultset into a list

Tags: java, jdbc

The aim of the code here is to Read a record by selecting a column.

I have following columns in the SQL DB.

```
------------------------------
|id | Topic | Comment | Time |
------------------------------
```

What I want to do is:-

1. Read the DB
2. Able to select rows by Topic
3. Show or Return the values of selected rows by Topic

The Topic could be duplicated, however the duplicated values should not been seen during the process of selection but the values of all column should be retrieved (as well as duplicated ones).

```
public class ReadRecordTopic{
       // JDBC driver name and database URL
       static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
       static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/STUDENTS?user=root&password=";

       //  Database credentials
       //static final String USER = "username";
       //static final String PASS = "password";

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           Connection conn = null;
           Statement stmt = null;

           try{
          //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

          //STEP 3: Open a connection
          System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
          System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

          //STEP 4: Execute a query
          System.out.println("Creating statement..." + "\n");
          stmt = conn.createStatement();

          String sql = "SELECT id, Topic, Comment, Time FROM Registration";
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

          //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
          while(rs.next()){
             //Retrieve by column name
             int id  = rs.getInt("id");
             String Topic = (String) rs.getString("Topic");
             String Comment = rs.getString("Comment");
             String Time = rs.getString("Time");

              String menu [] = Topic.split(",");
              Object[] selectionValues = menu;
              String initialSelection = "";

              Object selection = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                            "Please select the Topic.", "Reseach Forum Menu",
                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, selectionValues,
                            initialSelection);

             String a = "Research Topic: " + Topic + "\n";
             String b = "[" + Time + "]" + " Comment:" + Comment + "\n";

             if(selection == Topic){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, a + b);
             }     
        }

          rs.close();
       }catch(SQLException se){
          //Handle errors for JDBC
          se.printStackTrace();
       }catch(Exception e){
          //Handle errors for Class.forName
          e.printStackTrace();
       }finally{
          //finally block used to close resources
          try{
             if(stmt!=null)
                conn.close();
          }catch(SQLException se){
          }// do nothing
          try{
             if(conn!=null)
                conn.close();
          }catch(SQLException se){
             se.printStackTrace();
          }//end finally try
       }//end try
       System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }//end main
    }//end JDBCExample
```

Comment: And what problem have you run into while doing this?

Comment: Usually normal local variables do not start with capital character _(Topic, Comment and Time in your code)_ in Java

Answer (score 0):

1- Create Registration.class

```
public class Registration{
private int id;
private String topic;
...
...
...
//getters and setters 
}
```

2- Change your sql and function name for what do yo want and use it.

```
//for order topic
String sql = SELECT id, Topic, Comment, Time FROM Registration order by topic.

//function for just spesific topic

public class ArrayList<Registration> getRegisWithTopic(String topicName){
String sql = SELECT id, Topic, Comment, Time FROM Registration order by topic WHERE TOpic = topicName ;
}
```

3- in while create new Registration.class and add to ArrayList and return this list

```
ArrayList<Registration> newList = new ArrayList<Registration>();

while(rs.next()){
             Registration newReg = new Registration();
             //Retrieve by column name
             newReg.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
             newReg.setTopic(rs.getString("Topic"));
...
...
...
             //add this obj to list
             newList.add(newReg);
}


return newList ;
```